# split no. of rows into equal batches

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and would like to split the rows into batches(adding additional column like batch_no ).

e.g  I have a table with Single column cust_no and total=20 rows and split them into 5 batches like 1,2,3,4 and 5.

expected output like...

```
cust_no batch_no
23123   1
2313    1
23      1
323123  1
123     1
23      2
213     2
123     2
2123    2
2123    2
23123   3
2313    3
23      3
323123  3
123     3
23      4
...
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the number of batches then use `ntile()`:

```
select t.*,
       ntile(5) over (order by null) as batch
from t;
```

Note:  The `order by null` means that you do not care about the ordering.  It is arbitrary and not reproducible.  You might want to include some criteria -- say an id column or creation date or something so the batches are more homogenous.

If you want batches of a certain size, then use `row_number()` and arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (order by null) % 4) as batch
from t;
```

In some databases, this would be:

```
select t.*,
       mod(row_number() over (order by null), 4) as batch
from t;
```

Comment: thanks alot. , I was more looking for 2nd solutions. do you mind explaining the 2nd one?

Comment: @Roger . . . `row_number()` returns an enumerated value.  This is then divided into four equal groups using the *modulo* operator -- based on the remainder when the value is divided by 4.  The `ceil()` function is not needed, so I removed it.

Comment: @Gordan when i use % it gives me error ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character".... ...and when used without ceil() i get output like.. ```cust_NO BATCH
32424    0.0002
243234  0.0004
342        0.0006
3424      0.0008 ```

Comment: @Roger . . . In Oracle you use `mod(row_number() over (order by null), 4)`.  Your question was not originally tagged Oracle.

Comment: yes i tried with mod , and i get expected output, thx, batches from 0 to 3....any way I get batch from 1 and not 0?

Comment: @Roger . . . Just add 1.  Mod returns values between 0 and n - 1.